# matching a line that doesn't contain specific text with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I want to do the following with regular expressions but not sure how to do it. I want it to match `one two` when `one two` is the beginning of the line unless the string contains `three` anywhere after `one two`.

Comment: Regular expression questions, even the very specific ones, seem to attract a fair amount of attention. I genuinely wonder why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html#item__pattern_) - something like this:

```
/^one two(?!.*three)/m
```

Here's [a tutorial on lookahead/lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Note: I've added the 'm' modifier so that ^ matches the start of a line rather than the start of the whole string.

Answer (score 5):

```
^one two(?!.*three)
```