# regex (regular expressions) pattern NOT containing a string

Tags: regex

It was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string), but the asker got satisfied with a 2 character finding answer. I repeat his basic question:

> Generally, is there any way, how to
>   say not contains string in the same
>   way that I can say not contains
>   character with [^a]?

I want to create a regexp that matches two ending strings and everything between, but only if no other occurance of a given string is found inside. **But I will be satisfied best with the general answer to the quoted question**

Example:

The strings are `"<script>"`and`"</script>"`

It should match

```
"<script> something something </script>"
```

but not

```
"<script> something <script> something something </script>"
```

Comment: Please take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436850/matching-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-specific-text-with-regular-expressions) question

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML? If so, you should better use an HTML parser.

Comment: No, I'm trying to filter out some stuff. This is just an example

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find that. it started with matching a line, and i must have skipped reading the rest of it ;)

Comment: If you are trying to filter or sanitize html, you should still use a parser

Comment: It's just for removing stuff for viewrew comfprt, yet still - any suggestions for a parsers written in javascript? :P

[I too recommend parsers when I see a server side regex on html]

Comment: @naugtur: when stuff you remove is html, you are better of with a parser. There are js html parsers out there http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+html+parser

Comment: +1 I didn't expect that. [noone expects the spanish inquisition...]

Comment: Yet still what I needed is easily (and at this moment already, thx) done with a nice regexp. I just show the content without scripts for a moment. The regexp output is never saved anywhere.

Comment: Anybody fancy comparing Alan's and Otto's expressions? I sense a little difference in behaviour, but I'm not sure. I've done what I needed, so it'd be for the future generations  ;)

Comment: naugtur: Alan's expression doesn't match when `<script>` or `</script>` is in the middle, mine is only filters `<script>`

Comment: Yeah, this I get. I was curious about the (?:(?! versus just (?!. But they're probably the same. I think it's just me lacking some reading on regex. BTW. Your willingness to answer it to the last bit is what I like here in stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read my answer to that question?  It gives a more general solution.  In your case it would look like this:

```
(?s)<script>(?:(?!</?script>).)*</script>
```

In other words: match the opening sequence; then match one character at a time, *after* ensuring that it's not the beginning of the closing sequence; then match the closing sequence.

Comment: I still don't understand what is going on in the parentheses and why they don't match, but I'll figure it out. thanx

Comment: This regex has unbalanced paranthesis. When I fix the expression, it doesn't match either of the strings.

Comment: @naugtur, I fixed the missing parenthesis. It might still not work, in which case your start and end tags are probably on separate lines. Try appending `(?s)` in front of the proposed regex, which will let the DOT meta char also match lines breaks: `(?s)<script>(?:(?!</script>).)*</script>`

Comment: Mea culpa! I should have tested it, even if I *have* posted it a dozen times before.  Thanks, Bart.

Comment: No problem Alan, it's comforting to see guys like you also make these (little) mistakes! ;)

Comment: The negative lookahead should be for `<script>` not `</script>`

Comment: @Otto: actually, it should be for both: `(?!</?script>)`; that matches the innermost set of possibly nested tags.  Of course, `<script>` tags shouldn't *be* nested, but apparently the OP isn't really matching those.  I should have read the question more closely.  Fixing it now.

Comment: In practice it's for </script> if You assume the tags have any sense. It's my example that is rather silly ;) First thing I've changed when using it was looking for !</script instead of !<script. If somebody nested a script it's better to remove all heading tags.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression for your problem is

```
"^<script>((?!<script>).)*</script>$"
```

This *shouldn't* be used for html manipulation. This doesn't address cases like

```
<script> foo <script type="javascript"> bar </script>
```

and many others. A parser is the correct solution here.

The more general expression for matching strings beginning with `START`, ending with `END` without the specific character sequence `foobar` in-between is:

```
"^START((?!foobar).)*END$"
```

Comment: I tuned it up and the input is a bit different, so there is no need to worry about html content.

Answer (score 1):

Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Lookarounds give zero width matches - meaning that they don't consume any characters in the source string.

```
var s1 = "some long string with the CENSORED word";
var s2 = "some long string without that word";
console.log(s1.match(/^(?!.*CENSORED).*$/));//no match
console.log(s2.match(/^(?!.*CENSORED).*$/));//matches the whole string
```

The syntax for negative lookahead is `(?!REGEX)`. It searches for the `REGEX` and returns false if a match is found. Positive lookahead `(?=REGEX)` returns true if a match is found.