# Sed: regular expression match lines without <!--

Tags: regex, sed

I have a sed command to comment out xml commands

```
sed 's/^\([ \t]*\)\(.*[0-9a-zA-Z<].*\)$/\1<!-- Security: \2 -->/' web.xml
```

Takes:

```
<a>

  <!-- Comment -->
  <b>
    bla
  </b>

</a>
```

Produces:

```
<!-- Security: <a> -->

  <!-- Security: <!-- Comment --> -->    // NOTE: there are two end comments.  
  <!-- Security: <b> -->
    <!-- Security: bla -->
  <!-- Security: </b> -->

<!-- Security: </a> -->
```

Ideally I would like to not use my sed script to comment things that are already commented.

Ie:

```
<!-- Security: <a> -->

  <!-- Comment -->
  <!-- Security: <b> -->
    <!-- Security: bla -->
  <!-- Security: </b> -->

<!-- Security: </a> -->
```

I could do something like this:

```
sed 's/^\([ \t]*\)\(.*[0-9a-zA-Z<].*\)$/\1<!-- Security: \2 -->/' web.xml
sed 's/^[ \t]*<!-- Security: \(<!--.*-->\) -->/\1/' web.xml
```

but I think a one liner is cleaner (?)

This is pretty similar: [matching a line that doesn't contain specific text with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436850/matching-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-specific-text-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with this:

```
startInsert="<!-- Security: "
endInsert=" -->"

whiteSpace="[ \t]*"
char="[0-9a-zA-Z^_)!-/:-@[-\{-~]"

sed "s/^\($whiteSpace\)\(.*$char.*\)$/\1$startInsert\2$endInsert/" $file 
sed "s/^\($whiteSpace\)$startInsert\(<!--.*\-->\)$endInsert/\1\2/" $file
```

Not as graceful as I was hoping for but works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

```
^([ \t]*)(?!<!--)([0-9a-zA-Z<].*)$
```

<s>You have to escape the parenteses and other stuff in order to actually make it work with sed.</s>

Tested the expression in an online [regular expression tester](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Unfortunately it seems that sed does not support lookahead (but `ssed` [does](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html)).
maibe you should try `awk` or `ssed`.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that (and different variations) but I could not get it to work.  It ends up highlighting nothing.

Comment: Upon further reading it seems sed does not support those expressions. you have to use ssed and active perl mode (-R). found that info here: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html

Comment: Coool.  That is what I thought too.  +1 for clarification

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk, If i get your requirement correct:

```
awk -F"," '!/<!--/&&NF{$0="<!-- Security: "$0"-->"}1' file
```

Comment: hmmm, really would prefer to use sed but +1 for suggestion.